# Custom AuthenticationFilter with token-based authentication

Tags: jhipster

I am using token-based authentication. I have a custom authentication filter which does a REST call to authenticate the user. I managed to create and configure the custom authentication provider but having trouble setting the order of the providers. I want the default DaoAuthenticationProvider to be the default and customProvider to be the secondary.

This is how I configured the customAuthenticationProvider

```
@Inject
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Inject
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

How can I configure customAuthenticationProvider to be the second provider?

PS: I couldn't Inject the customAuthenticationProvider into SecurityConfiguration.java as the Proxy couldn't be created until I added the following scope to customAuthenticationProvider.

```
@Component("alfrescoAuthenticationProvider")
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
public class AlfrescoAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you said about why you can not inject. My SecurityConfiguration class is as below:

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Inject
private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

@Inject
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Inject
private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Inject
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    auth.authenticationProvider(weixinAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public WeixinAuthenticationProvider weixinAuthenticationProvider() {
    WeixinAuthenticationProvider provider = new WeixinAuthenticationProvider(userDetailsService, passwordEncoder());
    return provider;
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    ......
```

I hope it can help.